# dog nails; how short is too short?

Tags: dogs, training

I've never cut his nails this far back and I've gotten his quick a couple times myself. As we were leaving the tech said "it's normal for their nails to bleed a bit when cutting" but everyone I've asked confirmed my fear and agreed this was wrong. I don't plan on taking him back to this specific vet but I'd like to know if these are in fact too short

thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Welcome! It seems like your question might be missing some information, can you please edit it to clarify your concerns?

Comment: And you might also want to edit for adding a picture with the cut claws, so we can understand what is the status ;)

Answer (score 4):

As a rule of thumb, if the claw bleeds, it was cut too short.

But in practice there are variations in the length of the quick of individual dogs. In my experience, the older your dog gets, the longer the quick gets. However, a vet or groomer who hit the quick of a claw should immediately adapt and cut all remaining claws slightly longer.

If a vet tells you that "it's normal for their nails to bleed a bit when cutting" then they have a habit of cutting the nails too short. I wouldn't let them cut my dogs nails ever again.